# Bind Combobox itemsource to xml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, data-binding

i'm trying hard to load comboBox items from an xml file.
Here is my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="ScenesXml" XPath="scenari-list/scenario" Source="http://192.168.40.18/LeafHouse/scenari-appartamento-5.xml"/>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <ComboBox Name="scenariCombo" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ScenesXml}}" DisplayMemberPath="@name" />
</Grid>
```

And here is a simplified version of the xml file:

```
<scenari-list>
   <scenario name="Fuori casa" value="fuori-casa">
      ...
   </scenario>
   <scenario name="Party" value="party">
      ...
   </scenario>
   <scenario name="ciao" value="ciao">
      ...
   </scenario>
</scenari-list>
```

I want scenario's names to appear inside the combobox.
I found the code i provided in lots of questions but it doesn't work for me.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML is case-sensitive, so `@Name` should not yield any results as the attribute's name is `name`.

=> `DisplayMemberPath="@name"`

Comment: This was just a typo in this sample. My code is correct and still doesn't give any result.

Comment: If your code *were* correct it would give you results. How about posting **your actual code** then?

Comment: my actual code is the same i posted above, i just made a typo writing it. I don't think it is helpfull to write it again. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out so that i corrected the typo.

Comment: Well, if i test your exact code (except changing the XML file path) it works for me. So either your application cannot download the XML file or your context code is interfering.

Comment: You are right, the proxy was blocking the request. Now i added an exception rule and everything is ok. Thanks. PS: do you think i should delete this question?

Comment: @andreapier: Yes you should, sadly no gain for me but the question will certainly not be useful to anyone else so it would just make it harder to find useful XML related questions.

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer as i cannot delete it. Thanks for your help